# Office 2007 destroyed, uninstall impossible, error 1635 (can't open patch package)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, windows-installer

At work I'm regularly working with office products such as Word and Excel. I'm using Office Enterprise 2007 and experience a serious problem.

Without having changed anything on my office installation I was suddenly unable to start any Office product. Earlier that morning I had already started Word which was running, but when I tried to start Excel it failed and so it did when trying to start Word, PowerPoint etc.

Everytime I tried to start an Office application there was a Windows Installer message telling me "Preparing installation", but it never stopped. The message disappeared and re-appeared instantly for minutes without anything happening.

I tried to repair it by using Software -> Microsoft Office Enterprise 2007 -> Change. The setup starts and closes itself after 5 seconds. Then I tried to remove it. The deinstallation starts and closes itself after 10 seconds. I had  a look at some error protocols of Windows and could see an error 1635 (unable to open package or something like that) so I Googled and found that there is a Microsoft fix for uninstalling Office suites. So I downloaded the FixIt tool from Microsoft (MicrosoftFixit50154); tried to run it, same result. It's preparing the removal, the Office setup is starting and in the FixIt console output I can see a lot of 1635 errors and then the removal is canceled.

I also tried to use the original Office setup CD/DVD but the msi files can't be opened. When I try to run `setup.exe` from CD it tells me to enter the product key. I enter it, the installation is started and then it just tells me "Microsoft Office Enterprise 2007 had an error" or something like that. I'm totally stuck and nothing is working and I'm starting to get really pissed off by Microsoft products. I can't uninstall it, I can't repair it, I can't find out what the error this. A totally messed up installation without having changed anything about office on my PC for 3 years. On a running system it is suddenly not working anymore. In the morning I started Word and when I try to start it or any other Office product again later the same day nothing is working anymore.

Oh after the setup from CD failed I tried to uninstall it again, now it tells me the product installation is damaged and I should try to run the setup from CD. I'm wondering whether I should cry or laugh.

I hope someone has a solution for this. If you need further information, just let me know

Products:

- Microsoft Windows XP Professional SP3
- Microsoft Office Enterprise 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem myself and had to perform a manual uninstall. Thankfully Office is relatively conservative with registry usage. Microsoft have published a guide on how to manually uninstall Office here, which I have used successfully:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218

Comment: That is *exactly* what I did 2 hours ago and it solved my problem. If I hadn't found it myself, you would have helped me a lot. :) Why the heck does stuff like this happen at all? So sad.